# Как запросом ввести капча vk python

Tags: python, html, requests

Хочу написать скрипт авторизации вк, но бывает вылазит капча, нужно ее введи, но как?

Мой код:

```py
headers = {"Referer": f"https://m.vk.com/login?role=fast&to=&s=1&m=1&email={data_l[0]}"
          , 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
payload = {'email': f'{data_l[0]}', 'pass': f'{data_l[1]}'}
    
    
with requests.Session() as S:
    page = S.get('https://m.vk.com/login')
    soup = bs(page.content, 'lxml')
    url = soup.find('form')['action']
    p = S.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    print(p.text)
```

В ответе есть такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

разгадать капчу я смогу сервисом, но как мне ввести капчу эту?

Comment: Что за сервис? Ну как правило на таких сервисах есть свое API.

Comment: Вопрос не актуален, лучше авторизацию через апи делать,иначе запросами так ограничение дает